# Play Games Services only works if the app is downloaded from the app store. UNITY

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to implement Play Games Services into my Unity game, however, the plugin simply won't work correctly. It tries to connect, shows the little green box with "Google Play Games", a loading circle show up and then slides to the side, after that nothing within the Play Games Services seen to work at all (no achievements, score board etc). However, when I actually publish the app to Google Play everything works perfectly just as it should. However, this is obviously extremely unpractical as it sometimes takes a couple of hours before updates actually go live. I'm kinda of a noob but I assume it's failing to authenticate for some reason but I'm not sure how to check that?

Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This has been a common problem in the current (and last build). I also have had this happen. From what you are describing following these steps could solve the issue. [Link to issue on GPGS github](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1800#issuecomment-316458084)

" If you do as well (have this problem), then you need to go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and then choose API manager from menu there, and go to credentials of your app (if your app isn't there yet you should add it using the search there). When you're in credentials of your app just replace SHA-1 certificate line with the one that shown in your App signing (it's in Release management menu of Google Play Console). There you'll see app signing certificate info, you need that SHA-1 line from there, then you just replace the one you have in credentials with that one, by default in credentials you have the one from your keystore you generate with Unity (it's also shown in the bottom, where it says Upload certificate in your Google Play Console page). "

Comment: So, so it was actually already set to the app signing certificate and i changed it to the upload certificate which worked fine when the app wasn't uploaded to gplay now the issue is that it doesn't work on gplay and when i try to change it back to the app signing cert it just throws this error even though i don't have any other active projects with that SHA1 "Duplicate fingerprint
The fingerprint you specified is already used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project"

Comment: If I understand you right, you followed the directions and changed the correct key. After that the app works/Auth gpgs via a build through Unity? When you go to download it from google play itself the app no longer auths? 

I thought this was happening to me as well and it turned out I was already signed into gpgs. Are you using logcat, this could help with knowing what is going on under the hood.